# using cocoapods in existing iOS project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

In our iOS project, we are using lots of libraries, but using then as static libraries (.a and .h). But many of the new libraries provides cocoapods interface. How can we keep all the static libraries and use cocoapods for new libraies which we are planning to integrate. Or do we need to do cocoapods for all libraries used in our project. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding CocoaPods to an existing project will not affect any existing use of libraries in the project. I added CocoaPods to one of my projects after years of only using static libraries and other frameworks.

The only adjustment you will need to make is when replacing a specific static library with a CocoaPod version. But that's fairly simple and is handled for each specific case.